# When executing following code, the yearofBirth of Author class is coming up as null?

Tags: java, variables, null

[image]When I check the yearofBirth of the author from within the hp variable and inspect object... it shows null as year of birth but in the jkr variable it shows the yearofbirth as 1965 instead of null. Why is it showing null through hp and how do I get it to show the yearofBirth instead?

The following is what I executed:
1st:

```
Author jkr = new Author("JK Rowling", "1965");
```

The `yearOfBirth` shows fine when inspecting variable

Then:

```
Book hp = new Book("Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone",
                   "1997",
                   new Author("JK Rowling"));
```

The `yearOfBirth` shows as `null` when inspecting? And I want the book code to show as

eg: Title: Harry Potter, Author: JK Rowling**(Born 1900)**... with the `yearOfBirth`

Answer (score 0):

```
Book hp = new Book("Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone",
                   "1997",
                   new Author("JK Rowling"));
```

In this case you're not initializing the `yearOfBirth` in `Author`'s constructor, so that field will assume the value you gave in your one-argument constructor, that is `null`.

```
public Author (String aName) {
       this.name = aName;
       this.yearOfBirth = null; // <--- HERE
}
```

If you want to initialize that field, you can use your other constructor for `Author` (as you did in your first example) or assign it a default value in this constructor.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: About doing what, exactly? I gave you two options. Also, as I told you in the other answer you should take a step back and re-read the book/tutorial you're using to learn. And if they don't have answer to this kind of question, change material because what you're using is very bad. Don't take this the wrong way, but stackoverflow is for solving problems you have with your code, not to teach you how to code from scratch.

Comment: above what you have said.. when I try and put the year of birth in the place of null..eg:this.yearOfBirth = aYear;... it says cannot find symbol variable aYear

Comment: Of course you can't. You're not passing it. You have to consider the `Author(String aName)` and `Author(String aName, String aYear)` constructors as two completely separate entities. One doesn't know about the other (unless you explicitly say so). If you do `new Author("JK Rowling")` how would you expect the constructor to know what to put in the `yearOfBirth` field? You're not passing it. As I said, if you need a `yearOfBirth` that makes any sense, use the other constructor in your client code by passing the year as well (`new Author("JK Rowling", "1965")`)

Comment: so I did this Author jkr = new Author("JK Rowling", new yearOfBirth("1965")); but that didnt work

Comment: Re-read my latest comment. That's not what I wrote. `new Author("JK Rowling", "1965")`. `new yearOfBirth("1965")` doesn't work, as `yearOfBirth` is not a class, it's a member of the `Author` class.

Answer (score 0):

As one does not want to provide the birth year at every book, one needs a lookup:

```
Authors authors = new Authors();
Book hp = new Book("Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone",
                   "1997",
                   authors.findByName("JK Rowling"));
```

A simplistic implementation:

```
public class Authors {
    Map<String, Author> mapByName = new HashMap<>();

    public Authors() {
        addAuthor("JK Rowling", "1965");
    }

    private void addAuthor(String name, String yearOfBirth) {
        mapByName.put(name, new Author(name, yearOfBirth));
    }

    public Author findByName(String name) throws NoSuchElementException {
         return Optional.ofNullable(mapByName.get(name))
                 .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchException(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to Now change the year of birth of the Author object to 1900 by executing the line:

jkr.setYearOfBirth("1900");

And again, execute:

hp.toString();

The expected result now would be:

Title: Harry Potter, Artist: JK Rowling (Born 1900)... basically yearofbirth should change but that is not working

Comment: `Author jkr = authors.findByName("JK Rowling"); jkr.setYearOfBirth("1900");`? One thing to err would be forgetting `this.` in `public void setYearOfBirth(String yearOfBirth) { this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth; }` - assigning the parameter to itself i.o. the field